# Differential Equations - Is the solution to $(e^y+1)^2e^{-y}dx+(e^x+1)^6e^{-x}dy=0$, $y=\ln(-5(e^x+1)^5+c)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[This is the problem. It is question 4.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCht.png) I typed the answer in explicit form, but my professor had said it is incorrect. Could someone check over my work, because I think I did have it correct. [My Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPrCy.png)

Because someone asked for my work due to bad handwriting:
$$(e^y+1)^2e^{-y}dx+(e^x+1)^6e^{-x}dy=0$$
Trying to seperate variables:
$$(e^y+1)^2(e^{-y})dx=-(e^x+1)^6(e^{-x})dy$$
$$\frac{-e^x}{(e^x+1)^6}dx=\frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2}dy$$
$$\int{\frac{-e^x}{(e^x+1)^6}dx}=\int{\frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2}dy}$$
Flip:
$$\int{\frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2}dy}=\int{\frac{-e^x}{(e^x+1)^6}dx}$$
where $u = (e^y+1), du =e^ydy$ and $v = (e^x+1), dv=e^xdx$
$$\int{u^{-2}dy}=-\int{v^{-6}}dx$$
$$-u^{-1} + c_1=\frac{1}{5}v^{-5}+c_2$$
Now, substitute:
$$-\frac{1}{e^y+1}+c_1=\frac{1}{5(e^x+1)^5}+c_2$$
The $c$ gets absorbed (also, this is the implicit solution)
$$-\frac{1}{e^y+1}=\frac{1}{5(e^x+1)^5}+c_3$$
Multiply out:
$$-5(e^x+1)^5-c_3=e^y+1$$
But $-c_3$ is the same as $+c_3$
$$-5(e^x+1)^5+c_3=e^y+1$$
$$-5(e^x+1)^5+c_3=e^y$$
Take the natural log of both sides:
$$\ln(-5(e^x+1)^5+c_3)=\ln(e^y)$$
$$\ln\left(-5(e^x+1)^5+c_3\right)=y$$
This is the answer I got. It took long to convert this to Latex, so there might be some discontinuities in the work, but the last answer is for sure what I got.

Comment: You can't be serious!!! Your "work" is impossible to read. How about writing one equation per line? Or better still, how about transcribing your work in TeX?

Comment: If you think your answer is the right one, just derive and plug it in the equation. If you come up with an equality, then your answer is good. Or use Wolfram Alpha to verify your answer.

Comment: I had typed my work in latex.

Comment: No, $-\frac1a=\frac1b+c$ is not equivalent to $-b-c=a$. Not even with a different constant.

Comment: Why? Wouldn't that just be $-\frac{b}{a}=1-bc$ $\implies$ $-\frac{b}{a}=1-c$ $\implies$ $-\frac{b}{a}+c=1$ $\implies$ $-b+ac=a$ $\implies$ $-b+c=a$? or as you said $-b-c=a$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are the variable terms containing $x$ and $y$, $c$ is the integration constant. Multiplying by $ab$ gives $-b=a+cab$, and the last term is **not** constant, can thus **not** be replaced with a new constant.

Answer (score 3):

The wrong step is here :

> $$-\frac{1}{e^y+1}=\frac{1}{5(e^x+1)^5}+c_3$$
>   Multiply out:
>   $$-5(e^x+1)^5-c_3=e^y+1$$

The correct steps are :

Multiply both left-hand and right-hand terms by $(e^y+1)(5(e^x+1)^5)$
$$\left(-\frac{1}{e^y+1}\right)(e^y+1)\big(5(e^x+1)^5\big)=\left(\frac{1}{5(e^x+1)^5}+c_3\right)(e^y+1)\big(5(e^x+1)^5\big)$$
Simplify :

$$-\big(5(e^x+1)^5\big)=\left(1+c_3 5(e^x+1)^5\right)(e^y+1)$$

$$ e^y+1=\frac{-5(e^x+1)^5}{1+ 5c_3(e^x+1)^5} $$

$$y=\ln\left(\frac{-5(e^x+1)^5}{1+c_3 5(e^x+1)^5}-1 \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The step from:
$$ -\frac{1}{e^y + 1} = \frac{1}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_1 \tag{1} $$
to:
$$ -5(e^x +1)^5-c_2 = e^y +1 \tag{2}$$
is wrong. Because if what you say is true then it implies that (1) and (2) are a tautology, but if you replace a term of (2) in (1):
$$ -\frac{1}{e^y + 1} = \frac{1}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_3 $$
$$ \frac{1}{5(e^x +1)^5+c_2} = \frac{1}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_3 $$
$$ 1 = \frac{5(e^x +1)^5+c_2}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_3\big[5(e^x +1)^5+c_2\big] $$
$$ 1 = 1+\frac{c_2}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_3\big[5(e^x +1)^5+c_2\big] $$
$$ 0 = \frac{c_2}{5\left(e^x+1\right)^5} +c_3\big[5(e^x +1)^5+c_2\big] $$
it is a polynomial equation if $u=e^x+1$, and the equation has a finite set of solutions of $u$ (thus $x$), and the set solution isn't a interval in $\Bbb{R}$, thus the implication from (1) to (2) is false, becaus it doesn't have sense.